# Trouble Creating Array of AnyPokemonCreator Using Type Erasers

Tags: swift

I have the following code to create an array of different creators in Swift. I used the type eraser approach so I can populate the same array with different types of creators.  When I try to create a list it gives me error saying.

```
error: heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional
let creators = [AnyPokemonCreator(PikachuCreator()), AnyPokemonCreator(BulbasaurCreator())]


import UIKit

struct Pikachu {
    let name: String
    let powers: [String]
}

struct Bulbasaur {
    let name: String
    let powers: [String]
}

protocol PokemanCreator {
    associatedtype Pokemon
    func create() -> Pokemon
}

struct BulbasaurCreator: PokemanCreator {
    typealias Pokemon = Bulbasaur
    
    func create() -> Pokemon {
        return Bulbasaur(name: "Bulbasaur", powers: ["Vine Whip"])
    }
}

struct PikachuCreator: PokemanCreator {
    
    typealias Pokemon = Pikachu
    
    func create() -> Pokemon {
        return Pikachu(name: "Pikachu", powers: ["Electric"])
    }
}

struct AnyPokemonCreator<Pokemon>:  PokemanCreator {
    
    private let _create: () -> Pokemon
    
    init<Creator: PokemanCreator>(_ creator: Creator) where Creator.Pokemon == Pokemon {
        _create = creator.create
    }
    
    func create() -> Pokemon {
        return _create()
    }
}

// THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
let creators = [AnyPokemonCreator(PikachuCreator()),  AnyPokemonCreator(BulbasaurCreator())]
```

Comment: The trouble is that your type eraser is still a generic. Different generic types are different types. So you do not have an array of a single element type.

Comment: You cannot type-erase away a function that has different return values. What is the return type of `creators[0].create()`? It has to be the same as the type of `creators[1].create()` or you haven't "erased" any types. And you can't have an Array of these. What would you like to *do* with creators? What code will use it without using `as`? That will tell us how to fix this. (You probably do not need or want a type eraser here.)

Comment: I am trying to erase the types so I can have an array of PokemonCreators. Keep in mind that PokemonCreator is a protocol that contain associated type.

Comment: I am following this article: https://slacktime.org/type-erasure-in-swift-84480c807534

Comment: This approach does not allow you to create an array of AnyPokemonCreator . That is not possible unless all the Pokemon are the same type (notice how in the example, the array only works because all of the types involved are ElectricCar; you can't put different kinds of cars in that array). That said, you probably do not need a type-eraser at all. They are not a magic bullet and in most cases indicate that you have a design problem. (Not always; there are good reasons for them. But they're much rarer than people think.) If you will explain what you want the *calling* code to do, we can help.

Comment: What is the next line of code? When you write `for creator in creators { ... }`. What will go in the block in your real program?

Comment: Thanks! I was just trying to learn Type Erasers. I did not realize that they are all the same type (ElectricCar). Thanks!

Comment: @MehreenAzam The article you should be reading is http://robnapier.net/erasure — which is by the very person who has been commenting on your question.

Answer (score 0):

First your init says you will supply an argument which clearly you do not do . Second what are you trying to do exactly? If you want someone to adhere to a protocol simply say I have what the protocol says I need. ie:

```
protocol PokemanCreator {
func create() -> Pokemon
}

class SomeSuperClass {
     var somethingShared: SomeValue?
}
class BulbasaurCreator: Pokemon, PokemanCreator {    
     var someBulbasaurVariable: SomeType = SomeInitialValue
     var/let name: String
     var/let powers: [String]
     static func create() -> Pokemon {
            super.init()
            return Bulbasaur(name: "Bulbasaur", powers: ["Vine Whip"])
          }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I want to create an array of PokemonCreator. PokemonCreator is a protocol with associatedType.

Comment: I am not inheriting any struct. Please take a look at the code.